# Live templates in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, code-snippets

I use [live templates for laravel](https://github.com/koomai/phpstorm-laravel-live-templates). When I want to insert snippet, for example `Route::get`, I press `ctrl + j`, type `route`, popup is shown:

[image]

How can I navigate to `Route::get` without using arrow keys? When I type colon (`route:`), it accepts the first snippet:

[image]

## EDIT

My completion configuration

[image]

Comment: Works just fine for me in PhpStorm 2016.1.1 (I'm on Windows 7, in case if this makes difference). Tested with my own templates though -- named them `Route::abc`, `Route::get` and `Route::note` -- pressing `Ctrl+J` and then typing `route::g` preselects `Route::get` just fine. Your behaviour could be due to your settings -- please show screenshot of your `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion`

Comment: I thought that if you change "Case sensitive completion" option from "First letter" to "None" it will do any better .. but does not like that it will. I believe (and my additional experiments seems to prove it) that the problem is that 1) you have stuff like `Helper::link_to_route` (your first 2 matches in the list) and 2) you typing `route:` (small `r` -- which matches your first 2 entries but not those starting with "Route::".

Comment: Try typing `Route:` -- should do the job (does for me now after adding additional custom template `Helper::route` to better simulate your situation). If you do not want to type `Route:` then consider editing templates (alter their abbreviations) and use `route::` there (abbreviations). Using all lower-case letters for abbreviations is definitely  better idea (all default live templates seems to use them with no capital letters)

Comment: You was wright! I typed `Route:` and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, if you know your live templates abbreviations well, you do not need to press <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd> (`Code | Insert Live Template...`) -- you would just type abbreviation and press your expand key (usually it's a <kbd>Tab</kbd>). For example, I have `t[TAB]` to be expanded into `$this->` and `rt[TAB]` into `return $this;`.

The point I'm trying to make here .. is that typing Live Templates this way is much easier when not bothering with small/capital letters and typing all small.

If you check all default live templates (excluding surround ones) you would notice that they all use small letters in abbreviations and no capital.

---

Back to your case: with your Live Templates, when you typing `route`, it better matches first two (`Helper::link_to_route` and `Helper::route`) than actual `Route::xxx` ones. Hence typing `route:` (adding non letter character) will trigger first (most matching) template in the list.

Your options:

1. Use proper capitalisation -- type `Route:` (notice the capital `R`) -- it will match `Route::xxx` better than other two where `route` is present
2. Edit actual abbreviations for those Live Templates -- make them using small letters only (so it will become `route::get` for example). This way you do not need to worry about letter cases.
3. Edit abbreviations for those Live Templates to be something shorter, uses small letters only and be unique. For example: rename `Route::get` to `rget`. If you use such template the most often then you can benefit from that a lot.